# Apps Script setValues Not Working Consistently in Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a snipped of code below which shows a set of updates and loops I perform on an array called pullData

I have observed that for some reason, although pullData correctly gets populated with different data upon each loop, setValues is not pasting the first set of data.  I moved the source of the 2nd set to test, and when alone, it does paste the first set.

So it appears the issue is with the loop. However, Logger.log(pullData) does accurately log the data from the first loop, so I don't understand yet why it is not pasting since the data is populated.

I've tried moving the .setValues line outside of the if(intake != null){} brackets too, but that returns the same results of only posting the 2nd loop's pullData values to the sheet.

I am not sure if it might be trying to write both .setValues at the same time. I have thought this but am not sure of how to test.

In terms of solutions, I have considered setting a different variable with the data from the other loop, however the purpose of this snippet is to cycle through folders and subfolders, identify sheets with 'intake' in the name, and paste the data for each of those sheets based on the parameters. My real data has many more Intake sheets than 2, so I don't think this would be best.

Another idea I am considering now is pushing the list of IDs for those sheets with intake in them into an array and then just using that instead of doing it all within the while(files.hasNext()) loop. I recognize there are some other pieces that could be rewritten/optimized like the intake if () section too.

However, before I explore other options, I would like to better understand what is wrong with my current setup and why the results are inconsistent to what I'm trying to do. I appreciate any thoughts, thank you.

```
while (subFolders.hasNext()){
    var xFolder = subFolders.next();
    var files = xFolder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xfile = files.next();
    var fileiD = xfile.getId();
    var name = xfile.getName();

    var intake = name.match(/(Intake)/im)
    var fl1 = "sheetIDremoved";
    var fl2 = "sheetIDremoved";

    if(intake != null){
      var testFl = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileiD);
      var testFlSS = testFl.getSheetByName("Data Input");
      var testFlSSLRow= testFlSS.getLastRow();
 
      var pullData = testFlSS.getRange(2,1,testFlSSLRow-1,11).getValues();
      pullData.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
      Logger.log(pullData.length);

      for(i=pullData.length-1; i>0; i--){
        if(pullData[i][0]== ""){
          pullData.splice(i,11);
        }
      }
        
      for(j=0; j<pullData.length; j++){
        if(fileiD == fl1){
          pullData[j].unshift("FL-1");
        }
        else if(fileiD == fl2){
          pullData[j].unshift("FL-2");
        }
      }

      Logger.log(pullData); //this part works properly each execution
        
      qaSS.getRange(qaSSLRow+1,2,pullData.length,12).setValues(pullData); //for some reason this doesn't paste on the first loop despite logger showing the data is there.
        
        
    }
   }
  }
```

*Edit
So, I created a more simplified version of the loops by hardcoding the intake fileIDs to an array called 'intake', and unfortunately, it still seems to be skipping the .setValues in the first iteration for reasons unknown to me as I've never had this happen.

```
    var fl1 = "sheetIDremoved";
    var fl2 = "sheetIDremoved";

for(i=0; i<intake.length; i++){
    Logger.log(intake[i]);
    var testFl = SpreadsheetApp.openById(intake[i]);
    var testFlSS = testFl.getSheetByName("Data Input");
    var testFlSSLRow= testFlSS.getLastRow();
    var fileiD = testFl.getId();
    if(fileiD == fl1){
          var identifier = "FL-1";
        }
        else if(fileiD == fl2){
          var identifier = "FL-2";
        }

      var pullData = testFlSS.getRange(2,1,testFlSSLRow-1,11).getValues();
      pullData.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
      Logger.log(pullData.length);

      for(j=pullData.length-1; j>0; j--){
        if(pullData[j][0]== ""){
          pullData.splice(j,11);
        }
      }

      for(k=0; k<pullData.length; k++){
        pullData[k].unshift(identifier);
        }
      Logger.log(pullData.length);

      qaSS.getRange(qaSSLRow+1, 2, pullData.length, 12).setValues(pullData);
      Logger.log("Success");

      }
  }
```

In this version too, all the Loggers work properly and show the data, but for whatever reason it just does not paste in the first loop.  The length of 'intake' is 2, and I know it is passing through each time because the data for both sheets appears in the Logger.

Comment: it seems to correct when adding Utlities.sleep(1000); followed by SpreadsheetApp.flush(); to the end of my code.